# Rails 4 on Elastic Beanstalk (AWS): Where do my prints go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new with Rails and with Elastic Beanstalk.

When I start a rails server in my machine I can see my prints if my code executes *puts "Something"*, and I can see the requests and access to the data bases too:

```
Started GET "/app/s?s=Search%20term" for 192.168.0.19 at 2015-02-11 14:13:46 -0200
Processing by AppController#s as HTML
  Parameters: {"s"=>"Search term"}
Something
Completed 200 OK in 743ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

How can I see this output when my server is deployed in the Elastic Beenstalk? Are they stored in some log file?

Thanks for your help?

Comment: What is your server configuration ? Are you using Passenger to deploy your app on EB ?

Comment: It's a 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.1.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)

Comment: I think you can find your app logs at `/var/app/support/logs/production.log`

Comment: It is not there :(, I don't even have the /var/app/support/ folder, maybe it is because I am not under production, I have RACK_ENV = development. In the /var/app I have two folders: containerfiles and current

Comment: I found it, it is on /var/app/support/development.log and there is another on /var/app/containerfiles/logs/development.log (I don't really know the difference), that's weird, I was sure I looked there before. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Actually I didn't found it, it just prints the DB access but not my puts

Comment: Click on the Logs from the EB Dashboard and select the option to view the last 100 lines from your logs.  Then you can see all the different logs that get written to; one of those will be your production log.